# Multi Edition of an app on Android-platform? [Android Build Variant]

Tags: android

I want to make several versions of my application for different customers, but the means by which design do you start and what is the best tool for the implementation of this structure, Eclipse or AndroidStudio?

I started to refactor my code and turn it into library but it is not enough. However I learned that Android Studio introduced the notion of variance with the concept of targets is what is the best tool for multi edition of my software?

Comment: I ask this because many of the developers have to ask: how industrialize its software for multiple clients?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend sticking with Eclipse for now as far as developing for a release and playing with Android Studio for now until it matures a little. According to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

> Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs. If you are not comfortable using an unfinished product, you may want to instead download (or continue to use) the ADT Bundle (Eclipse with the ADT Plugin).

So I wouldn't be to eager to use that as your main tool just yet unless you are extremely comfortable with working with software that you may need to find workarounds in

Comment: Thanks, Good to know. You're right and I agree with you on the fact that the software is not yet mature, but I'll try it in parrallel with eclipse.

Comment: You're welcome. I think that's safe for now. I'm sure its going to be a great piece of software once its fully developed but I just wouldn't completely trust it for an important project right now

Comment: I will wait for release V2.. :)